# JQuery Dialog interact with background page

Tags: jquery

JQuery Dialog will make the background web page to be disable

but I want to open a JQuery Dialog and use with background web page.

How to implement this function?

```
$("#"+element).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 450,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    closeOnEscape: true
});
```

Comment: can u please provide more information on what u r trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is set by the `modal` property. To allow the website to be interacted with when the modal is visible, set `modal: false`:

```
$("#" + element).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 450,
    width: 650,
    modal: false, // < change here
    title: title,
    closeOnEscape: true
});
```

See the [jQuery UI dialog() documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) for more information.